# Where was this music video with a dramatically lit bridge filmed?

Tags: identify-this

I have been trying to figure out for quite a while where a certain music video was taken from. It is not a typical video as it is showing a time lapse from a metro. Here are a few screenshots I thought might easily lead me to my target but I failed...

[image]

This one looks to be very promising, however the only thing I found with "YASDA" was a german automotive parts dealer...

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tokyo Yurikamome Line, view of the [rainbow bridge](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_Bridge_(Tokyo)&ved=2ahUKEwjY6JKcsfXyAhX6FTQIHQxFAPsQFnoECCMQAQ&usg=AOvVaw2S5DiF86n9QdCF2CMFntuw).

https://youtu.be/HlzW70kksiM?t=428:

[image]

Comment: If you get a nice room at the Hilton Odaiba you can get a nice view of both this bridge and the Statue of Liberty at the same time!

Comment: Funnily Tokyo was one of my first guesses but I have been there and I did not remember there being any bridge looking like the Brooklyn bridge so I had immediately ruled it out!

Comment: Also shame on me, in the extended description there was a link to the creator of the original video (the one linked in this answer)

Comment: @YanickSalzmann your pictures have some hints eg cars driving on the left and presence of subway/train.